# How to write binary data to stdin and read data from stdout without closing stdin?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe

I have a program that writes binary data to stdin and reads it from stdout.
But the program freeze and does not allow reading data from stdout until stdin is closed, how to avoid this behavior?
I would like a h264 stream to the process and get a jpeg image at the output without closing stdin. Is it possible?

```
class PictureGrabber:
    jpeg_start_code = b'\xff\xd8'
    jpeg_end_code = b'\xff\xd9'

    def __init__(self):
        self.h264_to_mjpeg = Popen("ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i pipe: -vcodec mjpeg -an -f mjpeg pipe:",
                                   stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
        self.stdin = self.h264_to_mjpeg.stdin
        self.stdout = self.h264_to_mjpeg.stdout
        self.buffer = b''

    def write(self, packet):
        self.stdin.write(packet)

    def read_frame(self):
        while True:
            self.buffer += self.stdout.read(1024)
            start_index = self.buffer.find(self.jpeg_start_code)
            end_index = self.buffer.find(self.jpeg_end_code)
            if start_index != -1 and end_index != -1:
                frame = self.buffer[start_index:end_index + 2]
                self.buffer = self.buffer[end_index + 2:]
                return frame
```

Comment: How are you calling `write` and `read_frame`? They need to be on separate threads or other async entities if you don't know exactly how many bytes of data per output frame.

Comment: If it must be done in one thread, you need to partially decode the output stream so you know how many bytes to read at a time. I think [QuickTime File Format](https://developer.apple.com/standards/qtff-2001.pdf) is what you need to learn about the mjpeg packet structure